# Build lazy-seq by multiplying previous term by constant

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm starting out with Clojure and, despite having an understanding of recursion, am having trouble thinking of the "right" way to build a lazy-seq for the following function:

I want to build a list of all the frequencies starting from middle C. My first element would be 120 (the frequency of middle C). To get the second element, I'd multiply the first element, 120, by 1.059463 to get 127.13556. To the get the third I'd multiply the second element, 127.13556, by 1.059463, etc etc...

What's the best way to do this in Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`iterate`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate) function for that.

```
(iterate #(* % 1.059463) 120)
```

If you are planning to expand this into something more complicated, then you would create a function that recursive calls itself inside a call to [`lazy-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq). (This is what `iterate` does internally.)

```
(defn increasing-frequencies
  ([] (increasing-frequencies 120))
  ([freq]
   (cons freq (lazy-seq (increasing-frequencies (* freq 1.059463))))))

(nth (increasing-frequencies) 2) ;; => 134.69542180428002
```

If you start to use this in a tight loop, you may also want to generate a chunked lazy seq. This will pre-calculate the next few elements, instead of one by one.

```
(defn chunked-increasing-frequencies
  ([] (chunked-increasing-frequencies 120))
  ([freq]
   (lazy-seq
     (let [b (chunk-buffer 32)]
       (loop [i freq c 0]
         (if (< c 32)
           (do
             (chunk-append b i)
             (recur (* i 1.059463) (inc c)))
           (chunk-cons (chunk b) (chunked-increasing-frequencies i))))))))
```

**Note:** I would advise against doing this until you have measured a performance problem related to calculating individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn get-frequencies []
  (iterate #(* 1.059463 %) 120))
```

See [`iterate`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate)

Or, if you want to use [`lazy-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq) explicitly, you can do this:

```
(defn get-frequencies-hard []
  (cons
   120
   (lazy-seq
    (map #(* 1.059463 %) (get-frequencies-hard)))))
```

Which will `cons` 120 to a lazy seq of every value applied to the map function.